# Beagleboard Qemu baremetal with UEFI

Tags: arm, qemu, beagleboard, u-boot, uefi

I am trying to boot a freertos app from UEFI on Qemu

1. When i run the app from uboot, using the below commands it runs without any errors

   `fatload mmc 0 80300000 rtosdemo.bin
    go 0x80300000`
2. An uefi application loads the elf file at 0x80300000 and then I tried two options.

My boot.s file is below

```
`start:
_start:
_mainCRTStartup:
    ldr   r0, .LC6
    msr   CPSR_c, #MODE_UND|I_BIT|F_BIT /* Undefined Instruction */
    mov   sp, r0
    sub   r0, r0, #UND_STACK_SIZE
    msr   CPSR_c, #MODE_ABT|I_BIT|F_BIT /* Abort Mode */
    mov   sp, r0
    ...
```

`
Disassembly file

```
`
80300000 <_undf-0x20>:
80300000:   ea001424    b   80305098 <start>
80300004:   e59ff014    ldr pc, [pc, #20]   ; 80300020 <_undf>
80300008:   e59ff014    ldr pc, [pc, #20]   ; 80300024 <_swi>
8030000c:   e59ff014    ldr pc, [pc, #20]   ; 80300028 <_pabt>
80300010:   e59ff014    ldr pc, [pc, #20]   ; 8030002c <_dabt>
...........
80305098 <start>:
80305098:   e59f00f4    ldr r0, [pc, #244]  ; 80305194 <endless_loop+0x18>
8030509c:   e321f0db    msr CPSR_c, #219    ; 0xdb
803050a0:   e1a0d000    mov sp, r0
803050a4:   e2400004    sub r0, r0, #4
`
```

1. use `goto 0x80305098` which is the entry point addr specified in the elf file. Now it jumps to `ldr r0, ..` instruction but after that it just seems to be jumping some where in the middle of some function rather than stepping into `msr` instruction.
2. Since in uboot its jumping to `0x80300000`, I tried by jumping to that addr, now it goes to instruction `b 80305098 <start>`, but after that instruction instead of jumping to `80305098` it just  goes to the next instruction `ldr   pc, [pc, #20]`.

So any ideas on where I am going wrong?

EDIT:
I updated boot.s to

```
start:
_start:
_mainCRTStartup:
    .thumb
thumb_entry_point:
    blx arm_entry_point
    .arm
arm_entry_point:
    ldr   r0, .LC6
    msr   CPSR_c, #MODE_UND|I_BIT|F_BIT /* Undefined Instruction Mode */
    mov   sp, r0
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: Are you by any chance jumping to this code in Thumb state?

Comment: I am not sure... Is there a way to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ARM code, but it sounds very much like it's being jumped to in Thumb state. The word `e59f00f4` will be interpreted in Thumb as `lsls r4, r6, #3; b 0x80304bde` (if I've got my address maths right), which seems consistent with "jumping somewhere in the middle of some function". You can verify by checking bit 5 of the CPSR (assuming you're not in user mode) - if it's set, you've come in in Thumb state.

If that is the case, then the 'proper' solution probably involves making the UEFI loader application clever enough to do the right kind of interworking branch, but a quick and easy hack would be to place a shim somewhere just for the initial entry, something like:

```
    .thumb
thumb_entry_point:
    blx  arm_entry_point
    .arm
arm_entry_point:
    b  start
```

Comment: Did you ```blx``` for ```bx```. As you said it starts in thumb mode. Now it runs until a point where it breaks at instruction ```str r1, [r0]```. So is this instruction valid, I read that 1st argument should be even register.
```Data Abort Exception PC at 0x803050F0  CPSR 0x600001D3 nZCveAIFt_svc  Translation fault on Section: write to 0x4020FFC8```

Comment: Looks like I had to disable the MMU.. Thank you

Comment: Ah, I always forget `bx` has no immediate form, thanks.

Comment: Loading app using efi is just too much trouble... Getting stuck all over the place